# How can I integrate Seaborn plot into Tkinter GUI with the scroll

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, seaborn

I am trying to plot using Seaborn in Tkinter.

i want to display this code :

`g = sns.pairplot(self.dataset)`

in a new window with the scroll for better display of the dataset in this function :

```
def sol(self):
        graph_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        graph_window.title("Dataset graphs")
```

i tried this code :

```
def sol(self):
    graph_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    graph_window.title("Dataset graphs")

    scroll_bar = Scrollbar(graph_window) 
    scroll_bar.pack( side = 'right', fill = 'y' )

        label = tk.Label(graph_window, text="Pairplot showing relationships between different                   features in the dataset.")
    label.pack(pady=10)
    g = sns.pairplot(self.dataset)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(g.fig, master=graph_window)
    canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    canvas_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    canvas_widget.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
```

but it show the graphs without the scrolling